# PATCH 405 (Method Not Allowed) VueJs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have route in group `'prefix'=>'admin'` in web.php

```
Route::post('/slideUpdate/{id}','SlideController@postSlideUpdate')
```

In Add.vue i call function update() in methods

```
axios.patch(`/admin/slideUpdate/${this.list.id}`,this.$data.list)
```

In SlideController i have function

```
public function postSlideUpdate(Request $request,$id)
{
    $product = Slide::find($request->id);..$product->save();
}
```

When i click button `@click="update"`i get error

```
PATCH http://minhquanbicycle.com/admin/slideUpdate/1 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Thanks

Comment: did you tried by changing to `axios.post` instead ? Are you sure this `\`/admin/slideUpdate/${this.list.id}\`` make right path ?

Comment: you are posting data via `patch` and receiving it in `post`, update your route aswell to `PUT` or `PATCH` instead post

Answer (score 2):

Change your route to:

```
Route::patch('/slideUpdate/{id}','SlideController@postSlideUpdate')
```

Hope it helps...